# "tRun EX" command gives "FATAL ERROR FROM T24.INITIALISE INVALID TERMINAL MODEL DEFAULT"

Tags: jbase, temenos

When starting Temenos T24 classic interface from TAFJ shell, I keep getting this error:

```
C:\Temenos\bnk\UD>tRun EX
FATAL ERROR FROM T24.INITIALISE INVALID TERMINAL MODEL &∩ú╛DEFAULT

C:\Temenos\bnk\UD>
```

I have R20 TAFJ installation with the MSSQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following command from DBTools:

```
JQL COPY FROM F.TERMINAL TO F.TERMINAL EBS-JBASE,DEFAULT
```

or (what the above command does) simply copy the record "EBS-JBASE" and save it as "DEFAULT" in MSSQL table "F_TERMINAL".

The issue is that each time a new session is created it gets assigned a "Port number", which is saved in the T24 table named "F.TERMINAL.USER" along with the default terminal type. This functionality has "migrated" to TAFJ from TAFC when running T24 Classic. When a new "Port number", that has never logged in before, is assigned to the current session - it tries to create F.TERMINAL.USER record with Terminal Model = DEFAULT, which is missing, hence the error. All previously "logged in" sessions have Terminal Model as "EBS-JBASE" as you can see in F.TERMINAL.USER table.